# how can I dynamically change the number of records that needs to be filtered out?

Tags: sql, subquery, tableau-desktop

The final report is going to be in tableau, while SQL will be used to pull records. So a solution in any of these two is appreciated.

I have three tables A,B,C. I need to sample a total of 30 records from these three tables for a report for each month. On a ideal scenario, it should be 10 records each from these table. But,if for some reason, one of the tables have less than 10 records for a month, the sample includes all the data. Also, it needs to be compensated from the other two tables. (15+10+5 or any other combination).

is there a way to dynamically achieve this?

I tried to create separate worksheets in tableau, and merge it in a dashboard, but that doesn't work. Plus, they all should be presented as one single report, not as separate reports to download.

Comment: SQL Server or Snowflake?  They're not the same thing and as such solutions would vary.  Please edit your question to clarify the tags.

Comment: @squillman Since I am connecting from Tableau, the query is in SQL. Edited the tags. Thank you.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Be careful using just "SQL" to refer to SQL Server.  SQL is a language, SQL Server is a product.  Products have different implementations of SQL thus the different solutions.

Comment: Is this a random sampling, or is table order important?

Comment: the order of the tables is not important. But, from past records, the table C seems to be problematic with less than 10 records. So, the extra records usually come from A or B. It can come either entirely from A or B or a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

This works coming from SQL. It does have the drawback of always trying to pull the missing rows from table a first, but if that is not an issue this should suffice.

EDIT: Removed extraneous `WHILE` bits and just used `TOP` to try and get 10 rows from each table to start.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, adata VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @b TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, bdata VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @c TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, cdata VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @a
VALUES
('a1'),
('a2'),
('a3'),
('a4'),
('a5'),
('a6'),
('a7'),
('a8'),
('a9'),
('a10'),
('a11'),
('a12'),
('a13'),
('a14'),
('a15')

INSERT INTO @b
VALUES
('b1'),
('b2'),
('b3'),
('b4'),
('b5'),
('b6'),
('b7'),
('b8'),
('b9'),
('b10'),
('b11'),
('b12'),
('b13'),
('b14'),
('b15')

INSERT INTO @c
VALUES
('c1'),
('c2'),
('c3'),
('c4'),
('c5')

DECLARE @dataset TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, datasource VARCHAR(10), mdata VARCHAR(10), sourceid INT)

DECLARE @countert INT = 0

--try to get 10 rows from table a
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (10) 'a' AS datasource
    , adata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @a a
ORDER BY id

--try to get 10 rows from table b
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (10) 'b' AS datasource
    , bdata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @b b
ORDER BY id

--try to get 10 rows from table c
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (10) 'c' AS datasource
    , cdata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @c c
ORDER BY id

--set the total counter to the current number of rows
SET @countert = @countert + (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @dataset)

--try to finish off from table a
WHILE @countert < 30
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (1) 'a' AS datasource
    , adata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dataset d WHERE datasource = 'a' AND d.sourceid = a.id)
ORDER BY id
SET @countert = @countert +1
END

--try to finish off from table b
WHILE @countert < 30
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (1) 'b' AS datasource
    , bdata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @b b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dataset d WHERE datasource = 'b' AND d.sourceid = b.id)
ORDER BY id
SET @countert = @countert +1
END

--try to finish off from table c
WHILE @countert < 30
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @dataset (datasource, mdata, sourceid)
SELECT TOP (1) 'c' AS datasource
    , cdata AS mdata
    , id AS sourceid
FROM @c c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dataset d WHERE datasource = 'c' AND d.sourceid = c.id)
ORDER BY id
SET @countert = @countert +1
END

SELECT * FROM @dataset
```

| id | datasource | mdata | sourceid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | a2 | 2 |
| 3 | a | a3 | 3 |
| 4 | a | a4 | 4 |
| 5 | a | a5 | 5 |
| 6 | a | a6 | 6 |
| 7 | a | a7 | 7 |
| 8 | a | a8 | 8 |
| 9 | a | a9 | 9 |
| 10 | a | a10 | 10 |
| 11 | b | b1 | 1 |
| 12 | b | b2 | 2 |
| 13 | b | b3 | 3 |
| 14 | b | b4 | 4 |
| 15 | b | b5 | 5 |
| 16 | b | b6 | 6 |
| 17 | b | b7 | 7 |
| 18 | b | b8 | 8 |
| 19 | b | b9 | 9 |
| 20 | b | b10 | 10 |
| 21 | c | c1 | 1 |
| 22 | c | c2 | 2 |
| 23 | c | c3 | 3 |
| 24 | c | c4 | 4 |
| 25 | c | c5 | 5 |
| 26 | a | a11 | 11 |
| 27 | a | a12 | 12 |
| 28 | a | a13 | 13 |
| 29 | a | a14 | 14 |
| 30 | a | a15 | 15 |